How to build a Git submodule as a standalone project in an NX workspace?
I'm working on an Angular project using NX and have a Git submodule located in the root directory of my NX workspace. I want to build this submodule as a standalone project and have the output placed in the dist folder of my NX workspace. However, I'm unsure of the correct configuration to achieve this within the NX framework.
Current setup:

NX workspace with standalone Angular project
Buildable git submodule located at the root directory of the workspace

Objective:

Build the Git submodule as a standalone project
Output should be placed in the dist folder of the NX workspace

What I've tried:

Attempted to configure the project.json file, but was unsuccessful

Question:
What is the best way to manage and build a Git submodule within an NX workspace? Are there specific configurations or steps I should follow to accomplish this?
